# How to parse some  WCF/RIA Services URL?

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-ria-services, wcf-client

Let's say I have some form where user input some WCF/RIA Services URL and he wants to save it and be sure that URL will work.

(The main condition is that it could be any WCF/RIA Services URL.)

**How to parse it correctly to make sure that this WCF/RIA Services  URL is valid?**

**Which the best strategy is?**

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "valid"? Would executing a webhttprequest and making sure you get 200 OK back be too simple?

Comment: @Paul Lemke. Cool! Could you please provide any sample of your approach?

Comment: Go with Rajesh's answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the code below to get back a status response to make sure that the URL is valid:

```
var request = WebRequest.Create(serviceUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
            if (request != null)
            {
                request.ContentType = "application/xml";
                request.Method = "GET";
            }
var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
            if(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                 //valid url, continue to persist.
            }
            else
            {
                 //invalid url throw your exception or show message.
            }
```